# How to delete pointer in method without errors?

Tags: c++

Here is method in my class:

```
void StartProgram()
{
    int q = 0;
    cout << "\nEnter figures quantity\n";
    cin >> q;
    Figure* Temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        Temp = new Figure;
        Temp->CreateFigure(255, 3);
        compose.insert(compose.end(), Temp);
        delete Temp;
    }
}
```

This method fills a vector "compose" by the objects of class"Figure". For this task I use a temp pointer variable. When I'm trying to delete this Temp variable, to avoid a memory leak - everything goes wrong. Without this delete - programm works well. I know, maybe this question is pretty stupid, but I really don't know what I should do in such situation, cause just leave this method without freeing memory is not an option, i think.

Here is an error window:
[image: error window]

Comment: Well, what does `compose.insert` do? Also, why do you create the objects with `new`? `Figure temp; compose.push_back(temp);` seems a lot safer. Note that `delete` on Windows sometimes decides to error _really_ far away from the original error. Did you debug your code yet?

Comment: because he prob. has a vector of pointers

Comment: Yes, i have a vector of pointers to objects. Because of that, I use default function - "insert" to fill this vector. Without pointers programs has troubles. I think it is expedient to use pointers here.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use pointers (for example, you really have a vector of polymorphic objects), use unique_ptr:

```
using std::unique_ptr<Figure> figure_p;
std::vector<figure_p> compose;
...
void StartProgram()
{
    int q = 0;
    cout << "\nEnter figures quantity\n";
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        figure_p Temp(new Figure);
        Temp->CreateFigure(255, 3);
        compose.insert(compose.end(), std::move<figure_p>(Temp));
    }
}
```

If you do not need an array of polymorphic objects, just put objects of type Figure into your vector.